# Add limitation to fix sidebar

Tags: html, css

I created a fix sidebar with menu in it. My problem is it overlaps my footer. I want it to stop before the footer. Here are my codes.

HTML

```
    <div class="maincontent">
    main content here
</div>
    <div id="leftCol">
                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
                      <li>menu1</li>
                      <li>menu2</li>
                    </ul>
    </div>

<footer id="mainfooter"></footer>
```

for the css

```
.affix-top,.affix{
  position: static;
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
  #sidebar.affix-top {
    position: static;
    margin-top:30px;
  }

  #sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top:70px;
  }
}

#sidebar li.active {
    border:0 #eee solid;
    border-right-width:4px;
}
#page-wrap { 
  margin: 15px auto; 
  position: relative; 
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed; 
  margin-left: 10px; 
}
```

and the js

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
      offset: {
        top: 245
      }
});
```

Any answer is really appreciated from the community.

Comment: Any JSFiddle or other example is really appreciated from the poster.

Comment: You could add some `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` equals the height of the footer to your `#sidebar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add height using jQuery according to window size to sidebar.

In js add

```
function setHeight(){
var winHeight = $(window).height();
$("#sidebar").css("height", winHeight - yourFooterHeight);
}
```

In css add

```
#sidebar{overflow:auto;}
```

In your body tag call js function

```
onresize="setHeight()" onload="setHeight()"
```